# Carousel com duração de exibição diferente para cada item

Tags: jquery, carousel

Como eu poderia fazer um *carousel* com um elemento, sendo que cada elemento terá uma duração de exibição diferente? Ex.: Um (elemento) de 5 segundos; outro de 8 segundos.

Consegui fazer com o *Slick* do *jQuery*, porém não consigo estipular o tempo que cada elemento é exibido. Como posso fazer isso?

**HTML**

```
<div class='container_banner'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>


  <div class='single-item2'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".single-item").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: true,
});
$(".single-item2").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: true,
});
```

**CSS**

```
.container_banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5bqk68j/3804/

Comment: Isso https://jsfiddle.net/5t3ts4gy/1/ ?

Comment: Wagner vc quer que o item 1 fique um tempo X o item 2 um  tempo Y, o item 3 um tempo Z etc... Ou vc quer Dois Slider um com os intens mais lento e o outro com os itens mais rápido por exemplo? Como o Valdeir fez?

Comment: Quero que o item 1 fique um tempo X o item 2 um tempo Y, o item 3 um tempo Z etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto com diferentes valores para cada elemento do slider e chamar o callback `beforeChange` ([veja documentação](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)) para alterar a duração (`autoplaySpped`). Lembrando que o nome de cada item do objeto deve terminar com o número em sequência dos index: 0, 1, 2...:

```
var speeds = {
   // tempos em segundos
   item0: 5,
   item1: 8,
   item2: 1,
   item3: 5,
   item4: 15,
   item5: 1
}
```

Evento que chama o método:

```
$('.single-item').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  slick.options.autoplaySpeed = speeds['item'+nextSlide]*1000;
});
```

Nas opções de cada slider, você coloca no `autoplaySpeed`: `speeds.item0*1000`.

**O código todo fica assim:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   var speeds = {
      // tempos em segundos
      item0: 5,
      item1: 8,
      item2: 1,
      item3: 5,
      item4: 15,
      item5: 1
   }

   $('[class^="single-item"]').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
     slick.options.autoplaySpeed = speeds['item'+nextSlide]*1000;
   });

   $(".single-item").slick({
     dots: true,
     infinite: true,
     speed: 500,
     autoplaySpeed: speeds.item0*1000,
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
   });
   $(".single-item2").slick({
     dots: true,
     infinite: true,
     speed: 500,
     autoplaySpeed: speeds.item0*1000,
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
   });
   
});
```

```css
.container_banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='container_banner'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>


  <div class='single-item2'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ao invés de speed seria o duration no código do slick

Comment: Na documentação não tem o duration.

Comment: entendi, eh que isso é dinamico e cada slide tera um tempo de exibição, como poderia fazer?

Comment: Os dois sliders ou cada item dentro de cada um?

Comment: Vou ver se consigo achar onde alterar a duração e não o speed

Comment: Era o autoplaySpeed que define o tempo que o item do slide fica parado. O speed não deve ser alterado porque só a velocidade que se move.